# Delphi 7 refcount error when copying a record to dynamically allocated memory

Tags: delphi, automatic-ref-counting

I faced a strange behavior in Delphi when assigning a record type variable with a managed string field to a dynamically allocated buffer. What's wrong with it and how could be corrected?

```
type
  PRec = ^TRec;
  TRec = packed record
    Foo: integer;
    Bar: string;
  end;

procedure Error;
var
  P, Q: PRec;
  R, T: TRec;
begin
  R.Foo := 1;
  R.Bar := 'Bar';
  T := R; // Ready
  Q := @T;
  Q^ := R; // Ready
  GetMem(P, SizeOf(TRec));
  P^ := R; // Access violation in _LStrAsg at 
           // "MOV     ECX,[EDX-skew].StrRec.refCnt"

  R := P^; // Just to keep reference while debugging
end;
```

Comment: Malom, what exactly is the strange behavior?

Comment: The access violation was it. I could have been more explicit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your record is a managed record. As such, it needs to be initialized. Your code uses `GetMem` which does not initialize the record. Instead you should use `New`. Replace

```
GetMem(P, SizeOf(TRec));
```

with

```
New(P);
```

Likewise when you need to deallocate, you must finalize the record. Use `Dispose` rather than `FreeMem`.

It is possible to initialize and finalize manually if, for some reason, you need to do that. That would look like this:

```
// allocate and initialize
GetMem(P, SizeOf(P^));
Initialize(P^);

// finalize and deallocate
Finalize(P^);
FreeMem(P);
```

Comment: It should be noted that in this case the pointer has to be initialized only because the record contains a string. `Initialize(P^)` can be safely used instead of `FillChar(P^, SizeOf(P^), 0)` with one difference: *If the variable specified in a call to Finalize contains no long strings, variants, or interfaces, the compiler eliminates the call and generates no code for it.* See [System.Initialize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/System.Initialize)

Comment: @fantaghirocco Thank you. I agree that `Initialize` is much better

Comment: `Initialize` is better idiomatically but in 99% it is much slower compared with `FillChar`